# Do any browsers support the CSS3 pseudo-element "marker"?

Tags: browser, css

The spec [specifies](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#markers) that one can modify list-item (`li`) markers using the pseudo-element "marker" like so:

```
li::marker { color: blue; }
```

But I can't seem to get it to work in any of my browsers.

Do any browsers support this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: +1 Thanks for asking this question! I wouldn't have know about this part of the spec without it.

Comment: What you did wrong was assume that just because a W3C TR is publicly available, it automatically makes it a canonical part of "the spec" and that therefore implementations must exist for you to use the features as described. From the preamble: "Publication as a Working Draft does not imply endorsement by the W3C Membership. This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress."

Comment: 6 years later and people are still looking for this and apparently it's not being implements. I guess we'll have to keep using hack-arounds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

2021 update: all modern browsers have added support for `::marker`

- Firefox since v68
- Safari since v11.1 (limited to `color` and `font`)
- Chrome (and Edge) since v86
- Opera since v72

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker#browser_compatibility

Comment: As of March 2014 it appears that no major browsers have implemented this as yet.

Comment: As of October 2015, the situation is the same. There’s no according CanIUse page for it, but the support status can be tracked on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/marker/).

Comment: As of Feb 2016, this is still the case.

Comment: As of Sept 2016 this is still the case.

Comment: doesnt work on safari still despite caniuse

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

Comment: @eric-blue Without looking at it myself, there is partial support at a minimum and, apparently, "flux in the definition" of `::marker`.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use `:before` instead?

```
li {
 display: block;
 list-style-position: inside;
 margin: 0;
}
li:before { 
 content:" • ";  
 color: green;
}
```

Comment: Possibly, but that's not really what the question is about.

Comment: True. Somebody might find it helpful until it becomes supported though.

Comment: Using CSS-generated bullets instead of default browser-generated bullets changes the size and position of the bullets. This need not prevent from using this workaround, but you should consider whether it is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

While no browsers support the spec, Firefox has it's own way of doing things:

```
li::-moz-list-bullet {
color:blue;
}
```

Source: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205202

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the color of the marker *alone*, however you can change its image using list-style-image see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#list-content0). Work-around:

```
<ul><li style="color:blue;"><span style="color:black">test</span></li></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the color bit was just as an example. I really do just want to know whether any browsers support this specific pseudo-element, as such. (I'm specifically looking to use the `content` property.)

Answer (score 0):

No browser supports this but the (list-style-type: and list-style-image) properties can be used or the pseudo before and after classes.