# How to style markers in an ordered list that uses start attribute?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

How do you add styles to the HTML "start" attribute?

I am unable to target the number even if I apply styles to the entire ordered list tag.

```
//CODE:
<ol start="50">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

OUTPUT:

50. Coffee
51. Tea
52. Milk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<ol> with numbers another color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488830/ol-with-numbers-another-color)

Comment: Hey Mr Lister, it's not a duplicate since this question is specific to the "start" attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In what way is your question different from a question where the list starts with 1?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` properties for this. You have to use the `:before` pseudo element on the list items though.

Here is an example.

First you have to start the counter. You can do that with the `counter-reset` property.

```
ol {
  counter-reset: item 49;
  list-style: none;
}
```

The syntax for counter-reset is as follows

> counter-reset: none|name number|initial|inherit;

Here we're giving the name, followed by the number you want to start after. Since it starts at 0 by default, you want to choose 49 and not 50.

We can finally begin styling our numbers to make it look pretty. We do this with the `:before` pseudo-element. In the `content` property, we can include the value of our counter, which we defined with the counter-reset property above.

```
li:before {
   margin-right: 10px;                           // Gives us breathing room after number
   padding: 3px;
   content: counter(item);
   background: lightblue;
   border-radius: 100%;                          // Gives circle shape
   color: white;
   width: 1.2em;                            
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```css
 ol {
   counter-reset: item 49;
   list-style: none;
 }
 li {
   counter-increment: item;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 li:before {
   margin-right: 10px;
   padding: 3px;
   content: counter(item);
   background: lightblue;
   border-radius: 100%;
   color: white;
   width: 1.2em;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<ol start="50">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

It should also be noted that `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` only work on IE8 or higher.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment

Answer (score 4):

For anybody seeing this question in 2025:

> [***The `::marker`
>   pseudo-element***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudo-element)
>
> This specification defines a new type of pseudo-element, the
>   `::marker` pseudo-element, which is generated by list items to
>   represent the item’s marker (the bullet or number identifying each
>   item).

This pseudo-element can be styled like a real element and would satisfy the requirements in the question. Unfortunately, it currently enjoys zero browser support.

More info:

- [W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudo-element)
- [Do any browsers support the CSS3 pseudo-element "marker"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572353/do-any-browsers-support-the-css3-pseudo-element-marker)
- [CSS-Tricks: `::marker`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/marker/)

Comment: That was actually a proposition that didn't make it, so I'm not too sure it will resurface in a few years.

Comment: @MrLister, *didn't make it* or *hasn't made it*? It's still in the W3C draft. Is there anything saying it's been permanently dropped from consideration?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use some element like `<span>` to separate number style and list item style, something like this:

```
<style>
    ol > li { color: #00F; }
    ol > li > span { color: #000; }
</style>

<ol start="50">
  <li><span>Coffee</span></li>
  <li><span>Tea</span></li>
  <li><span>Milk</span></li>
</ol>
```